# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User

Tags: classcastexception

I have jira4.3 and using eclipse web service client I have generated client stubs(axis1.4).I am able to login and create issue but when I am trying to get the response , I get the error below. 
Please assist me in how to solve this, thank you.

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to
>   com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User
>         at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222) 
>         at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129) 
>         at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087) 
>         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source) 
>         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source) 
>         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source) 
>         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)

Below is the codebase used:

```
JiraSoapService jiraSoapService = soapSession.getJiraSoapService(); 
String authToken = soapSession.getAuthenticationToken(); 

RemoteIssue issue = new RemoteIssue(); 
issue.setProject(PROJECT_KEY); 
issue.setType(ISSUE_TYPE_ID); 
issue.setSummary("JIRA Ticket created via SOAP client: Without Component ID"); 
issue.setPriority(PRIORITY_ID); 
issue.setDuedate(Calendar.getInstance()); 
issue.setAssignee(ASSIGNEE_ID); 
issue.setDescription("In future tickets may be created through some Web form in this way "); 
RemoteIssue createdIssue = jiraSoapService.createIssue(authToken, issue);
```

Please help me to resolve this ,am using the jira4.3.Am not using any embeded user object anywhere,i dont know why it is trying to return embeeded user object.